# Yii CDbException.. invalid input syntax for integer: "1,075"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, yii, syntax-error

I started receiving this error from a production site since this morning and I'm wondering why I don't get the same in UAT or the developer environment..

Is any one familiar with an error like this ?

```
CDbException

Description

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1,076"

Source File

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\framework1.0\db\CDbCommand.php(372)

00360:             }
00361: 
00362:             if($this->_connection->enableProfiling)
00363:                 Yii::endProfile('system.db.CDbCommand.query('.$this->getText().')','system.db.CDbCommand.query');
00364: 
00365:             return $result;
00366:         }
00367:         catch(Exception $e)
00368:         {
00369:             if($this->_connection->enableProfiling)
00370:                 Yii::endProfile('system.db.CDbCommand.query('.$this->getText().')','system.db.CDbCommand.query');
00371:             Yii::log('Error in querying SQL: '.$this->getText().$par,CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR,'system.db.CDbCommand');
00372:             throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: {error}',
00373:                 array('{error}'=>$e->getMessage())));
00374:         }
00375:     }
00376: }
```

Attached a screenshot too..  the application is based on yii framework and postgress database.

[image]

Quick reply is highly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely someone entered `1,076` as a number in one of your input fields and you send this unmodified to the database. It should be `1.076` for the DB, though. You need to convert to the right format first.

Comment: Or, quite likely, `1076`; many people will write things like `1,123.00` (US/AU/UK form) or `1.123,00` (EU form), with a thousands separator. PostgreSQL won't accept integers with thousands separators.

Comment: @CraigRinger No, it does work in my development end. so i am wondering how this could be possible. Also the number 1,076 keeps changed sometimes to 1064 too.. and also this doesnt occur due to a user input or type misused...

Comment: I agree. This looks like a locale problem. Check PHP setting as well as available locales on both servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually because used number_format() function to a primary key and later in a code section it inputs the formatted number to search query.. i.e select * from user where id = 1,075 (instead of id = 1075)

Changing the number_format() function to apply only on selected areas worked.